# How to import keycloak user via docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to import keycloak users with docker-compose.

**What I have tried ?**

```
keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
    ports:
      - 8079:8080
    #    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realms/keycloak-realm.json:/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-realm.json
      - ./keycloak/realms/keycloak-users-0.json:/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-users-0.json
    command:
      - "-b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.http.port=8080 -Dkeycloak.import=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-users-0.json"
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgresdb
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak@12345
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin123
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-users-0.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-realm.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
    depends_on:
      postgresdb:
        condition: service_healthy
```

**My problem with above setup is that I am successfully able to import the realm and client settings but importing users fails.**

I can add users to the realm file but I don't prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

```
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-users-0.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/keycloak-realm.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
```

It seems you are overriding you first KEYCLOAK_IMPORT enviroment variable entry with a second KEYCLOAK_IMPORT entry. Could you try combining them into one? Perhaps using only one json file to contain both realm and users?